# How to Use ArrayList in more than one Activity?

Tags: android, arraylist

How i can access ArrayList from one Activity to another and also clear ArrayList value?

Comment: [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573796/keeping-a-variable-value-across-all-android-activities/8573991#8573991)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use setter/getter method for it.

```
public class MySetGet
{
    private ArrayList aList = null;

    public void setList ( ArrayList aList )
    {
            this.aList = a.List;
    }

    public ArrayList getList () 
    {
        return aList;
    }
}
```

Now you can set its value from any Activity/Class and get its value from any Activity/Class.

Answer (score 1):

The most simply and possible way to do the desired::

1.Create a simple public class say Data..
Now create a public static your Array list object.

Now access any where..

```
Data.listObj
```

2.Create the List object as public static in one activity and use in another via,

```
SecondActivity.listObj.clear();
```