# how i can pass element of edit text to another activity

Tags: android

im having a problem in passing information from one activity to another ... the idea is to choose from a vegetable market what do you need and choose the quantity this pic explain
[Activity 1](http://im41.gulfup.com/S5yJG.jpg)

i want to take all the information from the first activity so when i choose banana for example then put the quantity click on add to shopping cart the next activity would be like this
[Activity 2](http://im31.gulfup.com/4gvw5.jpg)

so how code i take the information from the first activity to the other ?!

Comment: there are several ways: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573796/keeping-a-variable-value-across-all-android-activities.

Depends of your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a new activity, you can send a bundle with it. Bundles can contain data like strings, booleans, ints, pretty much anything.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("value_1", value1);
bundle.putInt("value_2", value2);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

And in your second activities onCreate method, you can get the values from the bundle like:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value1 = bundle.getString("value_1");
String value2 = bundle.getString("value_2");
```

Comment: ok thanks vary vary match but could you give me hint for using just only arrays or using the method put extra for passing information form one activity to another

Comment: To pass arrays around just use the method of the bundle to put an array,e.g.:
bundle.putStringArray(key, value);
bundle.putIntArray(key, value);(key, value);

Comment: If it answers your question you can choose the tick above to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First associate EditText to a variable:

```
`EditText bananas = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bananastext);`
```

Then get value of it:

```
`int value = Integer.parseInt(bananas.getText().toString());`
```

Then create an Intent and attach on it value:

```
`intent.put("bananas",value);`
```

Then from the other activity create a Bundle and get value:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras;
Int value = extras.getInt("bananas");`
```